# How does Ember Data make the decision about what URL to look at when requesting data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following route file `index.js`:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('rental');
  }
});
```

In the tutorial on the Ember site, it states that Ember Data will then fetch data from `/rentals` url - why does it not look at `/rental` (as I had defined in the route file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Data follows restful endpoint design which states that resources endpoints are plural.  So when you ask the store to findAll for `rental` you are asking to find all of the records for the model type `rental` not to hit the endpoint `rental`.

https://codeplanet.io/principles-good-restful-api-design/

If your endpoints are non-standard, or just a pain to use with Ember Data, you can always create custom adapters and serializers.  Or you can just use normal ajax calls.